# Android ImageButton worked well in Activity. It doesn't work in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener, onclicklistener, imagebutton

I'm trying to convert a layout so that it will include fragments.
One of the views is an ImageButton that has a listener.
The code worked fine as an Activity but makes trouble as a Fragment...

First problem was that I couldn't use findViewById, 
but I was able to find the answer for that here and fixed it with getView().

I can't find an answer to the second problem...
after I declared:

```
ImageButton camBt = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

I want to set an on click listener:

```
camBt.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

But it keeps acting like the ImageButton (camBt) doesn't exist...
I don't even know what's the problem... it worked fine in the Activity...

Here's the full code.
Many thanks!

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);
    return V;
}

ImageButton camBt = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
camBt.setOnClickListener(listener);

ImageButton.OnClickListener listener = new ImageButton.OnClickListener()
{

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
Camera.open().getParameters();
}
}; 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move

```
ImageButton camBt = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
camBt.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

inside `onCreateView()`.

Like

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);

    // Here it is
    ImageButton camBt = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    camBt.setOnClickListener(listener);


    return v;
}
```

---

And one more thing you need to understand that variable name should starts with small letter. So you should use `View v` instead of `View V`.

Comment: replace getView() with V

Comment: @kalyanpvs Done! Was doing the same. Thank you for correction :)

Comment: @user2634069 Check xml file if there any error. And check error window.

Comment: Hey! It worked when I also replaced the getView with V!!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
ImageButton camBt = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
camBt.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

inside `onCreateView()` like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);

ImageButton camBt = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);

camBt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

return V;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);
        ImageButton camBt = (ImageButton)V.findViewById(R.id.button1);


         ImageButton.OnClickListener listener = new ImageButton.OnClickListener()
            {

            @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0)
                  {
                  Camera.open().getParameters();
                  }
              }; 
        camBt.setOnClickListener(listener);
            return V;
    }


  }
```