# ImageButton onClick not called in RelativeLayout in a Fragment using a transparent ActionBar

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

any ideas why my ImageButton isn't working in my Fragment?
The ImageButton contains a Drawable and is transparent.
When I place it in my RelativeLayout below, its working...

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rl_newsdet_root"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_newsdet_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_newsdet_back"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bt_back"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="left"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_newsdet_name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/cyan"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_newsdet_time"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_newsdet_name"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/tv_newsdet_text"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_newsdet_name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My onClickListener with AndroidAnnotations

```
 @ViewById
 ImageButton btn_newsdet_back;


    @Click(R.id.btn_newsdet_back)
    void back() {
       Log.i(TAG,"back");
       mActivity.popFragments();
    }
```

**EDIT**
onClick is working (called), when its below the TextView. Can anybody explain why?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "not working" ?

Comment: As I wrote in the title, onClick isn't working.
For me, it seems the button is not reachable but I don't know why.

Comment: again "is not working" is not really clear. The Log is wrote, or not ? It is just the "popFragments()" that is not executed ? We cannot know what behavior you expect and what actually happened.

Comment: onClick isn't working : onClick isn't called.
Might the transparent ActionBar be a possible reason?

Comment: I asked two questions, you didn't answer even one.

Comment: for me, I answer both - sorry.
When onClick isnt  called, whether the Log is written nor the fragment is popped.

Comment: check this link it will give some idea about your queries  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903654/android-imagebutton-worked-well-in-activity-it-doesnt-work-in-fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
The problem was I was using a transparent Actionbar which was the overlay I was looking for.

The following line in my onCreate() solved this:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as you said, everything works when you put the button inside the RelativeLayout below the reason should be that the second RelativeLayout has its parameters declared as:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Which means it is "filling" its parent, that is the original RelativeLayout containing the button. It's like you're creating a layer that covers the button and keeps any interaction with it from working. When you click on the button, you're actually clicking on the second RelativeLayout.

I didn't actually tried this, but you should consider setting:

```
android:layout_below="@id/btn_newsdet_back"
```

On the RelativeLayout below the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

**This is code of Fragment:** `TestFragment.java`

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.img2);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click on fragment ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

}
```

**This is layout of** 'TestFragment`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is code of** `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ImageButton imgButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    TestFragment fragment = (TestFragment) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    // fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, "");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

}
```

**This is layout of** `MainActivity`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.alarmdemo.TestFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here `ImageButton` is placed in a `Fragment` and it is working fine.

Comment: thx for your answer.
As you can see at my EDIT, onClick works when its below the TextView. So in general its working in a fragment.
There seems to be an overlay I don't understand.

Comment: You have two `RelativeLayout` and both having match parent in width and height. Try to change the width and height of inner `RelativeLayout`

Comment: setting width and height to wrap content at the inner layout has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add clickable in image button .Try following:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_newsdet_back"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="mymethod"
    android:src="@drawable/bt_back"
    />
```

## add in java

```
public void mymethod(View v)
{
  //your method
}
```

Comment: maybe there is no need for set clickable, but it also doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 0):

@Override

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample,
            container, false);
    addListenerOnButton();
```

}

```
   private void addListenerOnButton() {

    imageButton = (ImageButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }



    });     
}
```